# Average of the numbers in a given list

Tags: python, list

I have been told to write a function which calculates the average of the numbers in a given list. Empty arrays should return 0. Here is my code:

```py
def find_average(numbers):
    c = sum(numbers)
    for number in numbers:
        d = c / number    
        return d
    pass
```

Could someone explain why this doesn't work?

Comment: Have you learned yet how `for` loops work? If you `return` from the first iteration of a loop, you'll never even get to the rest of the loop. (Not that you need one in this case anyway.)

Comment: @Akio It's not clear what you think the for loop is supposed to accomplish here. Perhaps you could [edit] your question to explain this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `for` loop isn't necessary, since you're already using `sum()`. Once you've summed all the elements, the only thing you need to do is divide the sum by the number of entries in `numbers`:

```py
def find_average(numbers):
    if not numbers:
        return 0
    return sum(numbers) / len(numbers)
```

Comment: Alternatively, there's the one-liner `return sum(numbers)/len(numbers) if numbers else 0`

Comment: Or even `return mean(numbers) if numbers else 0`! But I suspect they're probably not allowed to import it from `statistics` for their assignment.

Comment: @CrazyChucky Or even `return len(numbers) and mean(numbers)`.

Comment: Or `return sum(numbers) / (len(numbers) or 1)`

Comment: @CrazyChucky One more: `return mean(numbers or [0])`

Answer (score 1):

```
def find_average(numbers):
    c = sum(numbers)
    if not numbers: # to avoid the division by zero
        return 0
    return c / len(numbers)

print(find_average([1, 2, 3]))
```

When you return it stops the function, so you were only dividing by the first element. To get the number of elements in a list you can use the keyword `len`.